# estimateGeometricTransform don't return the status

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

In the Matlab's help about estimateGeometricTransform says, that this function may return the status if it have some error (for example 'matchedPoints1 and matchedPoints2 inputs do not contain enough points.')
It should be written like this:

```
[___,status] = estimateGeometricTransform(matchedPoints1,matchedPoints2,transformType)
```

But in my case it doesn't work.

```
 [tform, status] = estimateGeometricTransform(matchedBoxPoints, matchedScenePoints, ...
     'projective');
```

After that command I'm using 'IF'-statement for checking the status and if it's not equal one, I need to do some commands. 
But I just get the error in the console:
**MATCHED_POINTS1 and MATCHED_POINTS2 do not have enough points.**
and the program stops.

What's wrong?

```
video = 'sample.avi';
hVideoSource = vision.VideoFileReader(video, 'ImageColorSpace', 'Intensity');
hVideoOut = vision.VideoPlayer('Name', 'Detected Box');     

boxImage = imread('cross2.jpg');
boxImage = rgb2gray(boxImage);

boxPoints = detectSURFFeatures(boxImage, 'NumOctaves', 10, 'NumScaleLevels', 15);
figure; imshow(boxImage);
title('100 Strongest Feature');
hold on;
plot(boxPoints.selectStrongest(100));

while ~isDone(hVideoSource)
    sceneImage = step(hVideoSource);
    sceneImage = imadjust(sceneImage);
bw = edge(sceneImage,'canny', 0.15, 2);
bw = imfill(bw,'holes');
se = strel('disk',1); 
bw = imopen(bw,se);
[B,L] = bwboundaries(bw);
stats = regionprops(L,'Centroid','EquivDiameter');
for k = 1:length(B)
 boundary = B{k};
 radius = stats(k).EquivDiameter/2;
 xc = stats(k).Centroid(1);
 yc = stats(k).Centroid(2);
 theta = 0:0.01:2*pi;
 Xfit = radius*cos(theta) + xc;
 Yfit = radius*sin(theta) + yc;

 if (radius > 10)
     rect = [xc-radius yc-radius radius*2 radius*2];
     croppedImage = imcrop(sceneImage, rect);
     rgbImage = cat(3,sceneImage,sceneImage,sceneImage);
     rgbImage = insertShape(rgbImage, 'Circle', [xc yc radius], 'Color', 'green');
     rgbImage = insertShape(rgbImage, 'Rectangle', rect, 'Color', 'yellow');    
 end

end
scenePoints = detectSURFFeatures(croppedImage, 'NumOctaves', 10, 'NumScaleLevels', 15);


    [boxFeatures, boxPoints] = extractFeatures(boxImage, boxPoints);
    [sceneFeatures, scenePoints] = extractFeatures(croppedImage, scenePoints);
    boxPairs = matchFeatures(boxFeatures, sceneFeatures);
    matchedBoxPoints = boxPoints(boxPairs(:, 1), :);
    matchedScenePoints = scenePoints(boxPairs(:, 2), :);


[tform, ~, ~, status] = estimateGeometricTransform(matchedBoxPoints, matchedScenePoints, ...
     'affine');
if (status ~= 1)
boxPolygon = [1, 1;...                           % top-left
        size(boxImage, 2), 1;...                 % top-right
        size(boxImage, 2), size(boxImage, 1);... % bottom-right
        1, size(boxImage, 1);...                 % bottom-left
        1, 1];                   % top-left again to close the polygon
    newBoxPolygon = transformPointsForward(tform, boxPolygon);

Poly = [newBoxPolygon(1,1) newBoxPolygon(1,2) newBoxPolygon(2,1) newBoxPolygon(2,2) ...
        newBoxPolygon(3,1) newBoxPolygon(3,2) newBoxPolygon(4,1) newBoxPolygon(4,2)...
        newBoxPolygon(5,1) newBoxPolygon(5,2)];

croppedImage = cat(3,croppedImage,croppedImage,croppedImage);
croppedImage = insertShape(croppedImage, 'Polygon', Poly, 'Color', 'green');
imshow(croppedImage);
else
croppedImage = cat(3,croppedImage,croppedImage,croppedImage);
croppedImage = insertText(croppedImage, [0 0], 'NO', 'TextColor', 'red');
imshow(croppedImage);
end

step(hVideoOut, rgbImage);
croppedImage = rgb2gray(croppedImage);
end
release(hVideoSource);
release(hVideoOut);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are other optional outputs before `status`:

```
[tform,inlierpoints1,inlierpoints2]  = estimateGeometricTransform(...)
```

The way you are calling the function, `status` actually contains `inlierPoints1`.

What you have to do to get the status and prevent the function from throwing an error is this:

```
[tform, ~, ~, status] = estimateGeometricTransform(matchedBoxPoints, matchedScenePoints, ...
     'projective');
```

A better way is to check the number of points before calling `estimateGeometricTransform`.

```
if size(boxPairs, 1) >= 3
   tform = estimateGeometricTransform(..., 'affine')
else
   % skip this frame
end
```

For projective, use 4 instead of 3.

Comment: So, I get the new error :) _The final column of an affine transformation matrix must consist of zeroes, except for a one in the last row._ (If there's 'affine' solution)

Comment: I try to use 'projective' and 'affine'. In 'affine' case: if I delete the 'satus', that I don't get this error.

Comment: Ok, I wrote all my code in the main topic. And what points do you mean?

Comment: Ok, try checking that you have enough matched points, before calling estimateGeometricTransform.  IIRC, you need at least 3 matches for affine and 4 matches for projective.

Comment: But I need to call estimateGeometricTransform for controlling the status, otherwise how I may now that I have enough matches?

Comment: You can just do the checking yourself. I have edited the answer.

Comment: If I try to use 'projective' in one moment I get this error: _Expected T to be finite._

Comment: Oh, thaks a lot again. :)

Comment: Type `dbstop if error` at the prompt. That will bring up the debugger as soon as an error is thrown. Then look at the matched points. Make sure you have at least 4 matches for projective. Look at the coordinates, see if anything could have produced infinities in the transformation matrix.